# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) on valid JSON when opening file in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, marshalling, data-conversion

I have a JSON file like so:

```json
{"cookies": [{"cookie": "cookie", "timestamp": 999999999998}, {"cookie": "cookie", "timestamp": 999999999998}]}
```

**My Source code**:

```py
def get_cookie():
    while True:
        try:
            f = open(f'xyz/cookies.json',)
            data = json.load(f)
            f.close()

            # more code here including a return statement...
        except Exception as e:
            print_error("Cookies", "Cookies", f"Exception {e} getting cookies")
            continue
```

**The code raises this error:**

> ```
> JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` on line 66 (`f = open(f'xyz/cookies.json',)`)
> ```

It only happens on the first time through the `while True` loop, the second time it returns successfully.

I have validated my JSON on [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/?code=) and it has confirmed it is valid.

I can’t work out how to fix this error.

Comment: Is this the entire JSON? I was able to run your code with the JSON without any errors. The error provided typically means something is wrong with the source data

Comment: I agree with Wondercricket. If the json does not change during runtime, this should either always work or never. Are you modifying the json in your script? Maybe by mistake? Does the timestamp of the file change? Are you always accessing the same file?

Comment: Yes, it is, I do have a thread which runs the `cookie_checker_()` function in [this](https://pastebin.com/smActkzS). However, I added asleep before its calls `cookie_checker()` and the exception still occurred. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the timestamp of the file @LydiavanDyke? If you mean the timestamp **in** the JSON, no this doesn't change.

Comment: No, I meant the timestamp of the file itself. Just to be sure, that the file is not modified by mistake. In the link that you just showed, I can see that the file is indeed rewritten, as you said. I see no other thread though, just a plain call from cookie_checker.

Comment: cookie_checker_ is called from a thread